# How to remove Window 11 Start Menus bloatwares via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-11

In the new Windows 11 Start Menus, there are apps like "TikTok" and "Prime Videos" that are not actually installed on the system, they would start installing when you clicked on the icon. This means that usual way of uninstalling via Powershell (ie: Remove-AppxPackages) does not work. In Window 10, I would get a round this by just replacing the orginal Start Menus layout config file with a blank one (effectively remove all pinned apps), then manually repin all the apps I wanted; but, this does not works on Win11 either.

So... does anyone know how to remove all of this visual bloats on the Start Menus via PowerShell (or any other command-line tools/languages, for that matter)?

Comment: Is [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-start-menu-layout-windows-11) of any help. I see it referring to a JSON file (same file you mentioned)? Might require editing a local system group policy with Group Policy Editor (maybe).

Comment: If there is one of those annoying Group Policies preventing you from making the change, the article says you'll need to modify it with Endpoint Manager instead of Group Policy Editor assuming it's your own personal system, or you have permissions on your domain to edit group policies.

Comment: `Get-appxpackage -name "insert name here" | remove-appxpackage` you can use * wildcard. Otherwise Winget -uninstall might be what you're looking for.

Comment: After a bit more digging, it is apparent that it is impossible to change to Start Menu Layout (i.e. which app is pinned to the start menu) via PowerShell. The old way of doing so, `Export-StartLayout` & `Import-StartLayout` or `Get-appxpackage -name "insert name here" | remove-appxpackage`, does not work; neither does trying to delete the shortcuts in the various Start Menu folders. There might be something in the Group Policy Editor, but that is not an option for my Home edition (or so I believe). Thanks for your suggestions, and I will post the answer here if I ever found it.

Comment: @VIN Have you found an answer to this issue?